# High avaialbility web/mysql on Raspbian Jessie

Tags: raspbian, networking

I've set up failover Apache2/MYSQL server with two RPIs with keepalived daemon.

I'd like to use checkers for so called realservers (so keepalived checks if specific server (i.e. Apache2, ...) is running, not just if machines are accesible over ethernet). I was unable to find any useful documentation about configuring keepalived to such extent. I am afraid that I simply lack knowledge to find info in keepalived sources, so I'd be grateful for pointers for docs I might have missed, or for help with that.

Comment: Might be helpful if you post your current `keepalived.conf` - obfuscate anything compromising...

Comment: Sorry, keepalived.conf would not be very useful since all I knew at time that I asked the question was that the checkers are existing... Meanwhile I figured out that there are docs on keepalived site, but marked deprecated, so I at first did not checked them out. Now, that I have read 'deprecated' docs, plus found some examples (which I can now understand), I was able to configure keepalived to suit my needs.